# RAID1 primarily used disk

Tags: performance, raid, raid1

I'm kinda new to the setup of raid-drives.
So my current setup looks like this:

- Disk1: 1x NVMe DataCenter Edition 960GB ("low" IOPS)
- Disk2: 1x NVMe Octane 480GB (high IOPS)

Disk 1 has 3 Partitions:

- D1P1: SWAP 16GB
- D1P2: Main (`/`) 400GB
- D1P3: RAID Mirror 450GB

Disk 2 has 1 Partition:

- D2P1: EXT4 450GB

Now I've set up a **software raid** using `mdadm`

```
mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/d2p1 /dev/d1p3
```

Now the actual question:

- Did I do anything correct to get the *high* IOPS from the Octane disk when using `md0`?
- Or what would I have to change to get the high IOPS?

In my scenario, the server is used as database and the data should be saved across 2 disks in case one fails to avoid data loss.

Comment: Test it. Test the performance you get with the 'fast' drive alone, the 'slow' drive, and with the raid over both. Or, if you already have the raid, test with a real-world load to see if you're even close to having it make a difference. If the 'slow' drive is fast enough for you, further optimizing is unnecessary. I don't know off the top of my head how md-raid distributes reads, one would hope it would take the relative performance of the two drives into account, instead of a naive 50-50 split.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could have created the array using the `--write-mostly` option, which makes the md driver avoid reading from the devices that follow it on the command line:

```
mdadm --create --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/md0 \
  /dev/d2p1 --write-mostly /dev/d1p3
```

The read performance for the array will then be that of the faster disk. Writing, however, will still be capped by the performance of the slower disk.

You can partially work around this limitation by also using the `--write-behind` option:

```
mdadm --create --level=1 --raid-devices=2 --bitmap=internal /dev/md0 \
  /dev/d2p1 --write-mostly --write-behind=1024 /dev/d1p3
```

But note that using `--write-behind` will **reduce the reliability of data protection** provided by your RAID1 array because writing operations will return before data blocks have been successfully written to *both* drives.

I would suggest using `--write-mostly` and avoiding `--write-behind`.

Comment: Thank you! This was what I was looking for but for everyone else following this - I recommend giving [1] also a read, since they got a valid point with the data reliability.

[1] https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/609539/432839

Answer (score 1):

> I'm kinda new to the setup of raid-drives.

You state you are implementing the RAID concept on NVME disks.

A quick search on *software raid with NVME* does return some interesting articles.

My understanding currently is RAID, preferably hardware raid, is limited to SATA and SAS connected disks.  No one has released a hardware raid card that plugs into the PCI-e bus that then can connect to *N* NVME storage devices.  NVME is just so new... and a direct connection basically to the PCIE bus, so using them in a RAID the only current option is with a software setup such as `mdadm`.

> the server is used as database and the data should be saved across 2 disks in case one fails to avoid data loss

if this at work and business related and not personal at home, and/or the database is important, I would recommend against software raid.  Software raid, handled by the operating system with some software (such as mdadm) does work and has its uses but it also has its pitfalls.  Simply unplug your server (power outage) and risk data corruption across all disks in the raid negating the entire reason you set up the raid in the first place.  Suggest you read as much as you can on RAID and best practices of RAID.

Normally you use the same make and model and **size** of disk.  I'm not familiar with the current capabilities of mdadm but RAID is typically done at the disk level before partitions are ever made.  Then one partition scheme is laid out across all disks in the RAID.  And then the importance of using the same make & model disk is so that one is not significantly slower than the other negating the purpose of the faster disk.  RAID performance is only as good as the slowest and smallest device in the array.  What you are trying to do as RAID-1 across 2 NVME *disks*, while I'm sure possible, in my opinion is not good... not if *data should be saved across 2 disks in case one fails to avoid data loss*.  Also realize data loss can happen in many ways, not just by disk failure.  I've experienced problems because of simple file system corruption (for whatever reason) more than from failed disks, such that having RAID was irrelevant.  RAID is not the end all be all to protecting data.

Always have a backup copy of your data on a completely separate device.  Assume that whatever two disk RAID-1 you have can become completely corrupted and unusable.

Comment: give this a read: https://www.adaptec.com/nr/rdonlyres/14b2fd84-f7a0-4ac5-a07a-214123ea3dd6/0/4423_sw_hwraid_10.pdf

Comment: perspective: https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/articles/Why-RAID-is-usually-a-Terrible-Idea-29/.  For you with a "server" and if a business then RAID is probably a good idea for you